# is there a Spring Cloud Stream Artemis / ActiveMQ binder?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

According to the documentation on https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream there is no Artemis  / ActiveMQ binder / implementation ?

Is there a plan to do one ?

RabbitMQ

Apache Kafka

Kafka Streams

Amazon Kinesis

Google PubSub (partner maintained)

Solace PubSub+ (partner maintained)

Azure Event Hubs (partner maintained)

Apache RocketMQ (partner maintained)

thanks

Comment: check this implementation https://github.com/snowdrop/spring-cloud-stream-binder-artemis

Answer (score 1):

Not that we know of. There is an implementation of a Solace binder. You can write an implementation for a binder if you need one. There are some articles about how to go about building one. See this for example: https://medium.com/@domenicosibilio/how-to-create-a-spring-cloud-stream-binder-from-scratch-ab8b29ee931b

Comment: There's a bit of an impedance mismatch between JMS and a fully-featured binder; specifically competing named consumers on topics (or broadcasting to multiple queues with a single write). Some brokers (e.g. ActiveMQ) have a proprietary solution but it's not standard JMS.

Comment: thanks for the details , our use case is more queue to queue ( more like federation  with  format processing (cloudevent format)  , not really brodcasting or groupe as mentionned in the documentation